# Can't create an options menu in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to implement options menu in Android 2.3 app with the help of ActionBarSherlock. But it doesn't display.Here is a simple XML layout file "breadcrumb_bar_menu" for options menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:id="@+id/inbox"
       android:icon="@drawable/topbar_btn_inbox"      
       android:title= "@string/about" />    

 <item android:id="@+id/sent"
       android:icon="@drawable/topbar_sent"      
       android:title="@string/about" />    
    </menu>
```

And here is my activity inherited from SherlockActivity:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.breadcrumb_bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

But I can't see options menu on the activity.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On which version of Android OS are you testing the app? Does it has hardware menu button?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal Please read my question attentively. I said about the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` in your menu xml item's attribute.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/inbox"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:icon="@drawable/topbar_btn_inbox"      
       android:title= "@string/about" />    

    <item android:id="@+id/sent"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:icon="@drawable/topbar_sent"      
       android:title="@string/about" />    
 </menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionoption, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set navigationmode for the deivce.
also is your device has hard menu key if yes then you will not see three dots of menu options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the system that you will be using menus:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make optionmenu to work as on other API's > 2.3.3 using Actionbarsherlock
I Did following :

Menu File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/navigateMenu" 
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:title="Menu"
android:orderInCategory:"9"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:titleCondensed="Menu">
<menu>
<item android:id="@+id/id1"
android:icon="@drawable/option1"
android:title="option1" />
<item android:id="@+id/id2"
android:icon="@drawable/option2"
android:title="option2" />
<item android:id="@+id/id3"
android:icon="@drawable/option3"
android:title="option3" />
</menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

In your Activity Code :
Take the reference of the parent MenuItem and attach it to actionbar using SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS property
See the Code for the Same :

Activity File :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sample_menu, menu);

//To make optionmenu visible on Actionbar for 2.3.3

menu.findItem(R.id.navigateMenu).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
        return true;
    }
```